# Can I create transition effects in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, effects

I have a form and couple of labels on it. I am creating a screensaver with the said form. So far, I have been able to have the text labels appear at different intervals.

Howveer, I want to take it notch further. I would like to have a text scroll in from the top or bottom in right or left direction. Can I do this directly with C#? How?

I would appreciate a helpful answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a WinForms, WPF, WebForms or MVC question?  It might be best to add a tag for which one it is to your question.

Comment: This is a Windows Form question. If that's what you mean.

Comment: Yep, I've updated the tags on the question to reflect this.

Comment: [I have typed your query into Google for you](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=winforms+animation&rlz=1C1CHLW_enAU510AU510&aq=f&oq=winforms+animation&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l5.1466j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Oh thanks! What did Google say?

Answer (score 0):

You want your text to "fly" on the form? If yes, why just not changing the label position?

Comment: I want the text to move from left to right or right to left, just like when you have text sliding in or out on a web form.

Comment: you can create a timer and move the position of the label, everytime the timer elapsed event gets called with an interval like 20 milliseconds.

Comment: I thought of this too. But isnt there some pre-defined class in C# for text effects such as this?

Answer (score 0):

Havent seen something like it... But if you know what is Expression Blend, you can make your own element styles (color, form, size, ANIMATION). You can try to realize it there...

Comment: Expression Blend is a design tool for WPF / Silverlight. Not winforms. winforms doesn't support any of that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer with a low interval and just use:

```
//Move right:
label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + 1, label1.Location.Y);
//Move left:
label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X - 1, label1.Location.Y);
```

Maybe something like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label1.Location.X <= Width)
        label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + 1, label1.Location.Y);
    else
        label1.Location = new Point(0, label1.Location.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You and any one else wanting to do something like that can simple use the following framework:

> **WinForm Animation Library [.Net3.5+]**
>
> A simple library for animating controls/values in .Net WinForm (.Net
>   3.5 and later). Key frame (Path) based and fully customizable.

https://falahati.github.io/WinFormAnimation/

```
new Animator2D(
        new Path2D(new Float2D(-100, -100), lbl_label.Location.ToFloat2D(), 500))
    .Play(lbl_label, Animator2D.KnownProperties.Location);
```

This slides the `lbl_label` label from -100, -100 to the location it was in first place in 500 ms.